# Select Group with Optgroup embedded in while loop

Tags: javascript, php

I have a while loop that fetches all the values in the `agentspec` table and sets them as an option in a select field.

My values in the `agentspec` table are grouped by the `category` field and I want to use the `category` field as my optgroup label.

This is what I've tried.  It currently outputs all the `category` field values followed by the all the `spec` values
eg.

```
Category: Farmer 
Category: Farmer
Category: Farmer
Category: Colour
Category: Colour
Spec: Grain
Spec: Sand
Spec: Fruit
Spec: Red
Spec: Blue
```

I want it to output the `spec` values according to what group they are set in the `category` field.

eg.

```
Category: Farmer 
Spec: Grain
Spec: Sand
Spec: Fruit
Category: Colour 
Spec: Red
Spec: Blue
```

Code:

```
$st = DBase::singleton()
            ->prepare(
                'select * ' .
                'from `agentspec` ' .
                'limit 0,30');

    $option = '';
    $optgroup = '';
    if ($st->execute())
    {
           while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
            {
    $id = $row->id;
    $cat = $row->category;
    $spec = htmlspecialchars($row->spec);
    $desc = htmlspecialchars($row->desc);

    $optgroup .=  '<optgroup label= '.$cat.'></optgroup>';
    $option .= '<option value = "agents/'.$id.'/themes">'.$spec.' , '.$desc.'</option>';

    }
    }


    ?>


    <select id="selectbox" name="" class=form-control>
    <option selected="selected">Select a Specialist Area
    </option>
    <?php echo $optgroup;?>
    <?php echo $option;?>

</select>
```

Comment: That’s a simple _control break_ that you want to programm here, so go read up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is a child element of optgroup, so you will have to do something like 
this crude [fiddle example](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ic6-s86):

Rewritten version for your snippet:

```
<?php
        $st = DBase::singleton()
                    ->prepare(
                        'select * ' .
                        'from `agentspec` ' .
                        'limit 0,30');


        $optHtml= '';
        $optgroups = array();

        if ($st->execute())
        {
            while ($row = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
            {
                $id = $row->id;
                $cat = $row->category;
                $spec = htmlspecialchars($row->spec);
                $desc = htmlspecialchars($row->desc);
                if (!array_key_exists($cat, $optgroups)) {
                    $optgroups[$cat] = "";
                }
                $optgroups[$cat].='<option value = "agents/'.$id.'/themes">'.$spec.' , '.$desc.'</option>';
            }
            foreach($optgroups as $label=>$optionsHtml) {
                $optHtml.= '<optgroup label="'.$label.'">'.$optionsHtml.'</optgroup>';
            }   
        }


?>

<select id="selectbox" name="" class=form-control>
    <option selected="selected">Select a Specialist Area</option>
    <?php echo $optHtml; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Works awesome! Thanks so much